# Loop through a "jagged" list

Tags: python, loops, jagged-arrays

So I have this list:

```
list = ["NYC Football", ["NY Giants","NY Jets"], "NYC Hockey", ["NY Rangers", "NY Islanders", "NJ Devils"]]
```

How would I loop through this list and only print out:

```
NY Giants
NY Jets
NY Rangers
NY Islanders
NJ Devils
```

Comment: Your list should be a `dict` in the first place: `{"NYC Football": ["NY Giants", "NY Jets"], "NYC Hockey": [...], ...}`. Is it possible to make that change?

Comment: Yes, it is. I guess I can then loop through the values in each key of that dict right?

Comment: Yes. What you have now is called an association list, where element 0 is a key that maps to element 1, element 2 maps to element 3, etc. It's essentially a representation of a `dict` in list form, but using a `dict` allows you to enforce the structure so that your code doesn't have to cater to the possibility of a malformed list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
my_list = ["NYC Football", ["NY Giants","NY Jets"], "NYC Hockey", ["NY Rangers", "NY Islanders", "NJ Devils"]]

for item in my_list:
    if type(item) == list:
        for i in item:
            print(i)
```

**Output**

```
NY Giants
NY Jets
NY Rangers
NY Islanders
NJ Devils
```

**Aside:** you shouldn't use the keyword `list` as a variable name. In my example I have altered it to `my_list`.

Comment: Ok. Cool. Ill try that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please don't use the name list for a list. You will shadow the built in list, which is going to give you a hard to detect bug sooner or later.

As chepner already mentioned in the comments, I strongly recommend converting your list to a dictionary in order to have a clean sport:teams mapping.

```
>>> lst = ["NYC Football", ["NY Giants","NY Jets"], "NYC Hockey", ["NY Rangers", "NY Islanders", "NJ Devils"]]
>>> teams = dict(zip(*[iter(lst)]*2))
>>> teams
{'NYC Football': ['NY Giants', 'NY Jets'], 'NYC Hockey': ['NY Rangers', 'NY Islanders', 'NJ Devils']}
```

To get the sports, issue

```
>>> teams.keys()
['NYC Football', 'NYC Hockey']
```

To get the teams, issue

```
>>> teams.values()
[['NY Giants', 'NY Jets'], ['NY Rangers', 'NY Islanders', 'NJ Devils']]
```

You could also un-nest this list with `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(teams.values()))
['NY Giants', 'NY Jets', 'NY Rangers', 'NY Islanders', 'NJ Devils']
```

I assumed that the order of the dictionary is not important. If it is, you can use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> teams = OrderedDict(zip(*[iter(lst)]*2))
>>> for team in chain.from_iterable(teams.values()):
...     print(team)
... 
NY Giants
NY Jets
NY Rangers
NY Islanders
NJ Devils
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the outer list, and only if the item is a list, iterate over it and print its items:

```
for thing in my_list: #don't call it "list"
    if isinstance(thing, list):
        for other in thing:
            print(other)
```

Another way:

```
for thing in filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)):
    for other in thing:
        print(other)
```